# Did Germany really replace wooden ties with steel ties on Russian Railroads during WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany

[This online article](https://rarehistoricalphotos.com/schwellenpflug-railroad-plough-1944/) says

> Soviet Union had a different gauge rail network and the Germans operated much heavier trains than the Russians, so when the Germans invaded they had to rebuild or modify the lines everywhere they went. Some of them were converted to standard gauge by moving the rails. **The Germans replaced the Russian wooden sleepers with steel sleepers**...

It has a lot of photos and talks about the Rail Plough used to destroy railroads as they retreated. However, I question the use of steel sleepers. Steel was surely much more expensive and rare than wood.

And there must be 1,000 or more sleepers per km of track, and Germany penetrated almost 1,000 km into the Soviet Union during Barbarossa. Would Germany really be spending that much steel, when they could just use wood?

Comment: Speculation: If they used steel ties it was most likely salvaged locally and not shipped out from Germany. Steel in that case would have been cheaper and faster. It seems likely that other rails could have been salvaged for this use - laying the running rails over sleepers made from cut up rails.

Comment: It looks like the author mixed up WWI (where Germans indeed used steel ties to build (not necessary replace) some roads in occupied territories) and WWII (steel ties started to be replaced with concrete ties before that in Germany itself). It is possible that steel ties *were* used at *some* intervals of *some* roads (e.g. reusing old ties from German roads) but their wide usage is very unlikely. It seems like the author just did not bother to find any detailed info in this regard as the main subject of his article was that Schwellenpflug, so he just fills the gaps with guesswork.

Comment: Keep in mind that sleepers aren't just any wood. It has to be treated with various chemicals that may be hard to find. Actually the first steel power pole in Sweden was actually put in place during WW2 due to shortages (when it later was replaced it was with a wood pole).

Comment: I remember reading that one of the major logistical problems for supplying the German front troops was that they had to *unload the German-gauge trains and re-load the supplies on the Russian-gauge trains*. And I know that Germany was about as [starved for steel](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/30372) as it was [starved for oil](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/39365), making the notion somewhat unlikely... then again, German bureaucracy did some other rather inefficient things...

Comment: Reading up on [steel sleepers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railroad_tie#Steel) indicates reasons why the Germans *may* have used them. 1) They use less ballast, ie the gravel under the tracks. There was [a question about a shortage of quality ballast in the Soviet Union](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/43182/4615). If Germany also had to make and ship ballast, steel ties might have made sense. 2) They're light and compact which is important if you need to ship them thousands of miles. 3) They can be made quickly, wood requires special treatment that takes time.

Comment: Wood only needs treatment if you wish it to last more then a few years.